# How to obtain full token address from uniswap/PCS router transactions (*types.Transaction)

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

When trying to obtain the token address from router transactions (add liquidity and remove liquidity taxes), the token addresses appear truncated, with 8 leading 0s and the 8 final characters missing. For example, instead of getting `0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c` for the BNB address, I'm getting `0x00000000bB4Cdb9cbd36B01Bd1CbaEBf2De08d91`.

[image]

In the screenshot, I'm  trying to unpack the data from types.Message but result is exactly the same when unpacking from the original *types.Transaction, which is obtained through ethclient. `TransactionByHash()` used on hashes for pending transactions.

I'm trying to unpack using the abi from the PancakeSwap router (as I'm using BSC).

Any help with this would be appreciated as I can't figure out why this would return the addresses in this format and would like to obtain the full addresses.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupidly simple answer actually, the abi unpack method is just looking in the wrong position by 4 bytes to the left, addresses can be obtained by calling the method on txn.Data()[4:] or by manually converting the correct bytes to address - tokenA := common.BytesToAddress(txn.Data[16:36])